# Losing post id wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am losing the post id when I am doing a wp-query. I need to have it where I am inserting a record, and before if it finds an existing record, as I am using it to find custom fields attached to the post. I am using a page template here and advanced custom fields.

Post Id being lost

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Template Name: Well Being Page Template
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
     * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
     */
     ?>

     <?php get_header(); ?>
     <?php 
    $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
    getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
    getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
    getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
    getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
    getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

    // args
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'wellbeing',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_key'      => 'ip',
        'meta_value'    => $ip 
        );




    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   // I HAVE THE POST ID HERE SO THAT I CAN REFERENCE IT IF THERE IS A RECORD FOUND USE THE POST ID FROM THE POST ?
    $isFound=false;
    ?>




    <?php
    $count = $the_query->found_posts;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    if(count==1)
    {
    $dateJoined = new DateTime($dateJoined);
    $expiredate = new DateTime($expiredate);

    $diff = $dateJoined->diff($expiredate);
    echo 'Days to end'.$diff->days;

    }
    endwhile;

    if ($count==0)
    {
    // Gather post data.
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => 'Opt In',
        'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
        'post_type'     => 'wellbeing',
        'meta_key'      => 'ip',
        'meta_value'    => $ip,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
    );

    // Insert the post into the database.
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    // I HAVE THE POST ID HERE OK BUT I ALSO NEED IT ABOVE AT THE WP_QUERY

    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify('+2 week');

    $currentdate = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());

    // save a basic text value
    $field_key = "expirey_date";
    $twoweeksaway = $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s');;
    update_field( $field_key, $twoweeksaway, $post_id );



    // save a basic text value
    $field_key = "date_joined";
    $value = $currentdate;
    update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // save a basic text value
    $field_key = "ip";
    $value = $ip;
    update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );

    // save a basic text value
    $field_key = "email";
    $value = wpse_email();
    update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );


    $dateJoined=the_field('date_joined', $post_id );
    $expiredate=the_field('expirey_date', $post_id );

    $dateJoined = new DateTime($dateJoined);
    $expiredate = new DateTime($expiredate);

    $diff = $dateJoined->diff($expiredate);
    echo 'Days to end'.$diff->days;

    } 

    ?>



    <?php
    echo 'Post Id'.$post_id;

    $dateJoined=the_field('date_joined', $post_id );
    $expiredate=the_field('expirey_date', $post_id );

    //Convert them to timestamps.
    $difference=(int)abs((strtotime($expiredate) - strtotime($dateJoined))); // 3

    ?>
<STYLE>
.myCheckbox input {
    // display: none;
    // Better than display: none for accessibility reasons
    position: relative;
    z-index: -9999;
}

.myCheckbox span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background: url("link_to_image");
}

.myCheckbox input:checked + span {
    background: url("link_to_another_image");
}
</STYLE>

    <div style="clear:both;">
    Welcome this page allows you to opt out of our well being program. You have <?php echo $difference.'day(s) to opt out click opt out button below';?>
    Do you wish to opt out of the well being program 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <form name="wellbeing" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">

       <input type="submit" value="Opt Out"/>
    </div>
    </form>  




     <?php wp_reset_query();     // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
     <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You should add comments to where you would like to use the original ID. It's very hard for an outsider to understand such a big chunk of code. Where was the post ID required? Where did you have it?

Comment: @janw I added some comments here for you mate as to where i need it

Comment: Can't you place it above the wp_query?

Comment: @janw no not how wordpress works